# How to undo "svn upgrade"

Tags: svn

So I am at work and installed the subversion packages on cygwin to keep my local checkouts of work files up to date. However, we use an older subversion at work and I accidentally did an svn upgrade locally. I didn't realize this caused an upgrade to the entire directory, so I am trying to undo these changes. I wanted to simply update my checkout, but it seems as though I used the wrong command from the recommendation list. Is there a way to undo the changes I just made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no corresponding "downgrade" command.

Your only option is to downgrade the Subversion packages you installed to whatever version your workplace uses, and then `checkout` your files from the repository again.